# RequireJs - Try to load a second time a library using the root path instead of the specified in config.path

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm quite new to requirejs and I'm getting headaches trying to find the following issue: requirejs is loading twice handlebars.js. First time it looks in the right path for the library, but don't know why it looks for that file a second time but this time it does not care about the config path specified. Does anyone have any clue about possible reasons?

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "lib/jquery-1.9.1",
    "underscore": "lib/underscore.min",
    "handlebars":"lib/handlebars.min",
    "jquery-ui":"lib/jquery-ui",
    "json2":"lib/json2",

    "auth_component":"lib/modules/Authentication",        

    "playlist_page":"pages/playlists"
  }, 
  shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'handlebars': {
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        },
        'json2':{
            exports: 'JSON'
        },
        'jquery-ui': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});
```

This is kind of the output i get in the console:

```
...
**/lib/handlebars.min.js GET 200 application/javascript require.js:1881**   
/lib/underscore.min.js GET 200 application/javascript require.js:1881   
/lib/underscore-min.map GET 404 text/html Authentication.js:7   
**handlerbar.js GET 404 text/html require.js:1881   471 B Pending**
```

As you can see, the first handlebar is retrieved from the lib directory. The second one is being tried from the root folder. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It't not loading it twice, the second file its seems to be trying to load is `handlerbar.js` and not `handlebar.js`.

I suggest you look into your folder structure and try get rid of the file. Or perhaps you misspelt the `handlebar` when you tried to load it as a dependency

Comment: as you said, it was because of misspelling the name when trying to load it as a dependency. Thanks